# How to customize the will_paginate link base?

Tags: ruby, hyperlink, href, will-paginate, customization

```
<%= will_paginate(@posts) %> 
# will generate the links like this '<a href="/posts?page=n">a link</a>'
```

What should I do if I want to change the href base on `/contents`, etc. `<a href="/contents?page=n">a link</a>` ?

It seems that there is no options for this , help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will probably have to write your own LinkRenderer. See [this](http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2008/8/3/roll-your-own-pagination-links-with-will_paginate) blog post, and the [code](http://gitrdoc.com/rdoc/mislav/will_paginate/df42582bde7c6c8ea2fd08ed532876909fb06500/classes/WillPaginate/LinkRenderer.html) for LinkRenderer.

Briefly:

in `environment.rb` you need something like this:

```
WillPaginate::ViewHelpers.pagination_options[:renderer] = 'MyLinkRenderer'
```

in `application_helper.rb`

```
class MyLinkRenderer < WillPaginate::LinkRenderer
  def page_link(page, text, attributes = {})
    url = url_for(page) # you should find a better way to do this...
    url.sub!('posts','contents')
    @template.link_to text, url, attributes
  end
end
```

Comment: In addition to this answer: The autoload_paths in Rails 3 don't include `lib/` anymore, so if you put `MyLinkRenderer` there, make sure to append the autoload_paths as well.